# MYSQL Set temporary columns for joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which is called dataTest and custlist. 
I want to join these tables based on the 'vlookref' in custlist tables, 
but the only columns that match is 'custacc' in dataTest table.
From dataTest tables, the area can be classified by region
for examples 'central,eastern,northern,southern' as Peninsular,
'kota kinabalu,lahad datu,sandakan,tawau' as Sabah, and
others as Sarawak.
How to archieve this so that I can inner join this based on 'vlookref' in custlist tables.Thx

dateTest schema

```
CREATE TABLE dataTest ( region varchar(50),custacc varchar(50));

INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('central','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('eastern','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('southern','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('northern','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('kota kinabalu','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('lahad datu','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('sandakan','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('tawau','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('bintulu','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('kuching','CT0135');
INSERT INTO dataTest VALUES ('sibu','CT0135');
```

custlist schema

```
CREATE TABLE custlist1 ( area varchar(50),vlookref varchar(50),custacc varchar(50),custname varchar(50));

INSERT INTO custlist1 VALUES ('peninsular','peninsular CT0135','CT0135','HP sdn bhd');
INSERT INTO custlist1 VALUES ('sabah','sabah CT0135','CT0135','Hup Trading sdn bhd');
INSERT INTO custlist1 VALUES ('sarawak','sarawak CT0135','CT0135','Master sdn bhd');
```

Comment: You should have a 3rd table, region against vlookref. And then you should be able to join data.

Comment: Thx for respond, but can it done by a query between this 2 tables that I mentioned above?

Comment: You can use switch case in the SQL itself. To map region with right vlookref, but that would involve hardcoding. And I would say it's a wasted effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query might help you:

select temp.region, temp.custacc, custlist1.* from 
(

select distinct dataTest.region,

dataTest.custacc,

(case when (dataTest.region = 'central' or dataTest.region = 'eastern' or dataTest.region = 'northern' or dataTest.region = 'southern' ) then concat('peninsular',' ',dataTest.custacc)

when (dataTest.region = 'kota kinabalu' or dataTest.region = 'lahad datu' or dataTest.region = 'sandakan' or dataTest.region = 'tawau' ) then concat('sabah',' ',dataTest.custacc)

else concat('sarawak',' ',dataTest.custacc) end) vlookrefdata
     from custlist1, dataTest

) temp JOIN custlist1 ON temp.vlookrefdata = custlist1.vlookref;

Comment: This seems to work,I will further out this query for my actual database.Thx

Answer (score 0):

From reading your table, it appears that it comes from an Excel sheet, where the only way you could do a lookup (vlookup) was to concatenate the two columns together. This isnt the case in sql, and you should simply join like this:

```
from datatest
join custlist1 on custlist1.area=datatest.region 
     and custlist1.custacc=datatest.custacc
```

Comment: Yes,table custlist come from Excel whereas I need to mapped out with the actual database table(dataTest). But how to join area and region where the values is not matching?

Comment: You need to specify whatever columns you join on. If its custacc only then just join on that column. If area and region are not expected to match then leave it out of the join. In your example, the vlookupref is always a concatenation of area and custacc which is why I suggested this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join condition using substring_index,

Try something like

```
SELECT ct.*, dt.* 
FROM custlist1 ct INNER JOIN dataTest dt 
ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(ct.vlookref,' ',-1) = dt.custacc
```

Or

```
SELECT ct.*, dt.* 
FROM custlist1 ct INNER JOIN dataTest dt 
ON ct.custacc = dt.custacc;
```

Try this [Demo](http://rextester.com/UZZIF52945)

Comment: This seems to work,but can you explain a bit how this query work?

Comment: @AmirulFahmi , I have split your column value **vlookref** so that second part can be compare with **custacc**. For understanding join refer link : https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: If thats how you means it, I can simply inner join it with dt.custacc=ct.custacc.Is it?

Comment: @AmirulFahmi Yes you can do that too.